# Merge many Pdf into Single pdf using Append bytes[] using C# or asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

**Problem:**

1. I have byte array in my datatable.
2. each `byte[]` is single pdf file for one order.
3. I just want to all these pdf `byte[]` in a single `byte[]` for single file.

I just want to save it to the browser.

I can achieve appending the `byte[]`, but it will create one `byte[]` data as pdf.

the following the sample i did here in console application actually I want in my web application.

here is my code:

```
public void NewPdf(string[] Pdf)
{

    byte[] newPdf;
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    foreach (var onepdf in Pdf)
    {
        newPdf = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(onepdf);
      //newPdf=System.Convert.FromBase64String(onepdf);
      // int resultPdf = newPdf.Length;
      // ms.Write(newPdf, 0, newPdf.Length);
      // var ms = new MemoryStream(new byte[resultPdf], 0, resultPdf, true, true);
       ms.Write(newPdf, 0, newPdf.Length);
       //ms.Write(baadF00d, 0, baadF00d.Length);

       //System.Buffer.BlockCopy(newPdf, 0, resultPdf, 0, newPdf.Length);
    }
    byte[] merged = ms.GetBuffer();
   // File.WriteAllBytes("testpdf.pdf", merged);
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(merged);
    int n = reader.NumberOfPages;
    Document document = new Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1));
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream("thugs.pdf", FileMode.Create));
    document.Open();
    PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
    PdfImportedPage page;
    int rotation;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < n)
    {
        i++;
        document.SetPageSize(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i));
        document.NewPage();
        page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
        rotation = reader.GetPageRotation(i);
        if (rotation == 90 || rotation == 270)
        {
            cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, -1f, 1f, 0, 0, reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i).Height);
        }
        else
        {
            cb.AddTemplate(page, 1f, 0, 0, 1f, 0, 0);

        }
    }
    reader = new PdfReader(merged);
    // we retrieve the total number of pages
    n = reader.NumberOfPages;
    document.Close();

}
```

Actually i am trying to do in asp.net mvc2....

i can return the `byte[]` in mvc2

```
return File(bytes, mimeType);
```

Comment: It's not clear what your question is.  Do you want to know how to return a file via a browser in MVC2?  Or are you having trouble merging the PDF files?

Comment: i want to merge two pdf byte[] as a single pdf and return the file using mvc2